# Old House with Buzzing Outlets

Tags: electrical

I bought a house in the last year. It was built in the 1950s. I'm not sure if it has been rewired since then but I've seen behind some walls and in the basement that the wiring all appears yellow or white ROMEX. I've checked behind a few outlets and the receptacles are all inside blue plastic housings inside the wall.

I've noticed whenever I plug in a device with a AC to DC converter like a laptop charger or a computer power supply I can hear a soft buzzing sound. I have to put my ear right to the outlet or the room has to be very quiet but I can hear it. It buzzes up and down, not a constant tone sound. I even heard the sound transfer from the wall to the inside of my computers PSU when its plugged in.

Should I be worried? Is this going to start a fire? Or is this normal and shouldn't impact the operation of my devices?

Comment: If it doesn't stay steady at 60 Hz, it's not from AC power.  You're hearing some other sort of machinery like an attic vent or radon system, and the wall is just a sound conduit.

Comment: Really? Because if I take my devices and plug them into different outlets in the house I hear the same noise right at the outlet. The ones in the kitchen do it just as well as the ones in the basement.

Comment: If you're finding yellow and white NM-B (commonly called "Romex" - it's a trade name that's become a common name like "Kleenex") and blue plastic boxes behind your devices, then your wiring has _definitely_ been updated since the 50s. That's a good thing™!

Comment: My bad, I missed the part where these things were wall-warts.  Wall-warts are not just hollow large bending space for wires, they actually have powered electronics inside.   Put a long extension cord on them so the wall-wart is far away from the wall, and listen again.  Is the noise still at the recep, or does it follow the wall-wart?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance - a wall-wart is? The plastic receptacle part of the outlet? This [thing](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTm8_Q9VF_alV6QrL7_NkEOAqLf_zkGIqivhS5ViwPEw2RVxQOIcf1kg_ZNlk4&usqp=CAc)?